# How can I calculate the max value in a polygon?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, max, polygon

I have an image and i used the `impoly` function to draw a polygon. I would like to calculate the max value in that polygon and also to receive the indices of where the value is. It sounds easy but I can't find a function that does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code using `roipoly` that creates a mask (`1` inside the polygon, `0` outside). As the `max` is wanted here, the code sets the excluded pixels to `0` (if `min` is wanted, set the outter pixels to `inf`).

```
%data
I = imread('pout.tif');
imshow(I);

%polygon
BW = roipoly;

%set to zero if outside
I(~BW) = 0;

%find max value (maxI) and its indexes (m,n)
[maxI,indI] = max(I(:));
[m,n] = ind2sub(size(I),indI)
```

Comment: you can use `-inf` and `inf` for the values outside the polygon.